# How to display images from web Laravel api to vue frontend?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuex

**i have an laravel api when i fetch in vue give me object like

products=[ {id:1,image:test1.jpg,price:100} {id:2,image:test1.jpg,price:100} {id:3,image:test1.jpg,price:100} ]

### Success loop object but i cant display image because it have stored in laravel backend in storage folder Any ideas how to get in my loop and display successful **

Comment: Depending on where your images are stored in the `storage` folder, you could use the public disk to host these images from your storage folder and then in your Vue code, you'd need to generate the URL to the image using the image file you get from your API. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: may i ask how should be link for eample in tag image src

Comment: Well, what’s the URL you follow to access and view one of these images in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

1- You have to make it sure that you are also sending proper url within api with file name.

```
[
 id: 1,
 image_name: image1,
 image_url: Storage::url('file_name'); // this will return full url of file, you can check this by opening it in browser.
].
```

2-Then you can loop the response and bind image_url with src property, this will show the image.

```
<div v-for="(product, key) in products" :key="key">
 <img :src="product.image_url" alt="" />
 ...
</div>
```

Note: Make sure you have run "php artisan storage:link" in terminal to create link of storage with public. read more https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-urls.